# Equivalence between apply and Isar styles in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

Are apply style and Isar-proofs equivalents? This is a question that I have thougth for some time. Of course, Isar-proofs are much more readable, maintanable and easy to write (?) but my question is whether you could prove exactly the same things with both styles.

As an example, I'm currently working on a proof where I need to leave:

```
apply(simp split: prod.splits) 
using some_lemma by fastforce
```

What is the equivalent form of these commands in apply and Isar style? Actually, I'm more interested in the Isar style since I'm told that it is bad style to mix styles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equivalent Isar style would be:

```
have "P"
  using some_lemma by fastforce
then have "Q"
  by (simp split: prod.splits)
```

Where "P" is represents the intermediate goal state after the first `apply`.

In general, anything provable can be proved both in Isar and in `apply` style; both have their strengths and weaknesses.

I personally use the style where I try to structure my proofs outside-in: outside (like induction) Isar, and if necessary, inside (like simplification, low-level stuff) with `apply`.

In general though I recommend you stay within Isar as much as possible.

Comment: what if "P" is a huge subgoal? would you paste it as it is?

Comment: in that case, for me writing using some_lemma by (simp split: prod.splits) (fastforce) works

Comment: @Javier That's always a trade-off. Often, the proof can be restructured to avoid huge intermediate statements. Other times, it can't.